# Multiple buttons in input group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement an input group that has multiple buttons on the left and for now only one button on the right as shown in this image:

[image]

The problem is, as soon as I have more than one button per side, the input field resizes to max width and kicks the one button out on smaller displays:

[image]

With only a button on the left and a button on the right, it works 100% on all screen sizes:

[image]

Le Code:

```
    <div class="input-group br">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary clear-search">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary qr-code">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control search" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group dropup">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    Search
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li><a class="buyer-identifier" href="#">Buyer Number</a></li>
                    ...
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="clear-search" href="#">Clear Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gp3s7gk9/)**

Any idea on how to make the first image work for all screen sizes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need the `btn-group` element...

```
    <div class="input-group br">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary clear-search">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary qr-code">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>
          </a>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control search" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group dropup">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    Search
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li><a class="buyer-identifier" href="#">Buyer Number</a></li>
                    ...
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="clear-search" href="#">Clear Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/5kkE9rUQri)

Answer (score 8):

Don't use two button group wrapper elements.

```
<div class="input-group br"> <span class="input-group-btn">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary clear-search">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
    </a> 
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary qr-code">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>
    </a>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gp3s7gk9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

use **btn-secondary** class

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">☺</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">SEND</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a Bootstrap 4 thing? I'm not sure it's relevant to this particular question.